# My app crashes when i run the code. ERROR Is: " android.widget.SlidingDrawer cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout"

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Below is my code, and whenever i run it, it would crash........

I'm trying to put a list of Strings into a ListView, but whenever i do i get the error message:

Fatal EXCEPTION: Main
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ss.website/com.ss.website.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SlidingDrawer cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.ss.website;


import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ListView listview;  
    private String[] planets;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
        planets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
        listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets));

    }


}
```

Comment: You should add your `R.layout.activity_main.xml` to this ticket, but it looks like you're attempting to incorrectly cast a `SlidingDrawer` to a `DrawerLayout` on the line starting with `drawer = ...`. Check to make sure that `R.id.slidingDrawer1` is the correct identifier you are attempting to access.

Comment: thanks cjohn for the reply, but what i don't understand is what do you mean "add you R.layout.activity_main.xml to this ticket". Do you mean the part of setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)???

Comment: Oh never mind, i understood what you meant  and got it working. Thanks so much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as it is: DrawerLayout is no subclass nor superclass of SlidingDrawer.

Comment: Ahh no wonder, i was thinking that DrawerLayout was the indication of SlidingDrawer. Thanks HEAPS to you both